# cannot create instance of viewmodellocator in c# mvvm light

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8.1

I have a project in which I have two instances of `ViewModelLocator`, each in different assemblies. When I try to run my app, it gives me an error at the very beginning saying:

> Cannot create instance of ViewModelLocator in first assembly.

I get this error if I reference the second DLL in the first project and then run it. The `ViewModelLocator` that runs is from the first one, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do so.

Can anyone guide on whether:

- I can have two ViewModelLocators in a LOC; and
- What is the right way of doing this?

Both my guide and co-pilot projects have ViewModelLocators. Here's my code:

```
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    xmlns:vm="using:Copilot.ViewModel">
    xmlns:vm="using:Navigator.Guide.ViewModel">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!--Global View Model Locator-->
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" 
                                 d:IsDataSource="True" />


        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: That won't even compile.  You have duplicate namespace definitions.

Comment: Yes that too and i was also registering it twice.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this just so that someone running into the same issue will be helped.

If you are adding mvvmlight 5.3.0 from nuget, go ahead and also add ModernUI.wpf version 1.0.9 and your app.xaml will need resources like the following,

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.Light.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:myApp.ViewModel" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```